# How to execute the Shell Script using Gradle

Tags: gradle

**A problem occurred starting process 'command 'sh''**

My Script was,

```
workingDir '/Users/admin/Desktop/Sample/'
commandLine 'sh', './start.sh'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can omit the `'sh'` and just call

```
commandLine './start.sh'
```

make sure your script has correct execution permission (just do `chmod 755 start.sh` to be sure)